# issues with variables when importing SASS file from external site

Tags: css, visual-studio, sass

I have a ***scss*** file starting with:

```
@import "styles";
@import url("http://lctools.lundbeckconsulting.no/SASS/STATIC/lct.public.scss");
```

Contains a media rule:

```
@media (max-width: $media-small-width) { //code }
```

But when compiling the file in Visual Studio I get an error saying that *$media-small-width* is an **Undeclared Variable**, even though it exists in *lct.public.scss* that's imported from the external site.

Using variables from *styles.scss* (local file) works as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because the import function will only import external files as a CSS import rule - it will not actually import the SCSS from that external file into the rest of your code.

You will need to declare your variables inside your local files. (This might not be the answer you were hoping for. Sorry!)

Documentation on import from SASS: http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#_import__import

Comment: no I was hoping for a little different logic, but that's not your fault! thanks :)