# Is there a way to import an external .SCSS file into a local .SCSS, and still get variables and mixins compiled?

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

I'd like to import a GitHub based .scss file into a local .scss file, and still get the compilation working. The question has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47143613/issues-with-variables-when-importing-sass-file-from-external-site/47143708#47143708), but there seems (seemed?) that the problem was unsolvable. Maybe does a plugin exist?

Comment: So you want to fetch an external web based file every time you compile? I'd be curious why you'd want that considering things like you'd have no version control etc like you would if you were using say imports from npm modules in a local build pipeline.

Comment: I'm trying to build my own set of mixins and variables to be reused in all my personal projects, as these mixins are always the same. It would be more convenient, even if I have to commit every change in this "master" .scss file. But maybe i'm blind to a more convenient method I've not heard about...

Comment: Just depends on how your projects are arch'd I suppose. Are you using like node, bower, or something else you could wrap that stuff into a handy little package to easily share/import between projects?

Comment: I know node (having it installed) and bower (by name), but after several researches I don't get what you meant by quoting those two. Does that "wrapping things into a little package" thing has a specific name for me to look for?

Comment: Sure there's lots of stuff out there for it, but again it just depends on your projects but as example could do [node](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-make-a-beautiful-tiny-npm-package-and-publish-it-2881d4307f78/) or even 'ol [bower](https://bower.io/docs/creating-packages/) or other options.

Comment: Thank you very much for the ressources, I'm studying the question with node, as bower appears to be maintained.